# Объяснение знака

Tags: предложение

Нажимаем на **Знаки** вверху страницы и читаем:

<kbd>Популист</kbd> Лучший ответ по рейт***е***нгу, превысивший принятый ответ**,** с более 10 баллами, более чем в 2 раза

Опечатка и неудачная формулировка.
Неужели это было написано авторами сайта "Русский язык"??
Нееет, не ими!
Источник -- [Stack Overflow на русском](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/badges).

Предлагаю исправить на обоих сайтах на:
<kbd>Популист</kbd> Лучший ответ с рейтингом, превысившим более чем в 2 раза рейтинг принятого ответа с более чем 10-ю баллами.

Answer (score 2):

Спасибо, это исправлено, сейчас используется такой текст:

> Ответ с наилучшим рейтингом, который обошёл более чем вдвое принятый ответ с рейтингом больше 10

Для справки: [Как принять участие в переводе сайта?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1032/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BC/1137#1137)